# Convert REST API described in OpenAPI specification to AWS API Gateway REST API described in Terraform template

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, terraform, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I have OpenAPI 3.0 specification (YAML) of my REST API and I need to describe the same REST API in Terraform template (HCL) as AWS API Gateway resources.

Are there any tools which could help me to convert it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

AWS' [API Gateway directly supports importing an OpenAPI 3.0 spec](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-api-gateway-adds-support-for-openapi-3-api-specification/) to define all of the relevant parts of an API Gateway.

With Terraform this can be done with the [`aws_api_gateway_rest_api` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_rest_api.html) and the [`body` parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_rest_api.html#body).

An example is given in the [tests for the resource](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/0efdad0c7cc5543c740b3e72c0efb6acce42484c/aws/resource_aws_api_gateway_rest_api_test.go#L850-L885):

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "test" {
  name = "foo"
  body = <<EOF
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "foo",
    "version": "2017-04-20T04:08:08Z"
  },
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/test": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response"
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "type": "HTTP",
          "uri": "https://www.google.de",
          "httpMethod": "GET",
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": 200
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
EOF
}
```

You can also use the `file` function to load the OpenAPI spec from your YAML file directly:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "test" {
  name = "foo"
  body = file("${path.module}/api.yml")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Actually I need to convert somehow my OpenAPI JSON to HCL format, not just inject it. Are there any options for this?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it?

Comment: It's convention for Terraform templates on my project, only because of this.

Comment: I think I'm failing to understand the value in rewriting this to fully describe the API in HCL. API gateways are a pretty horrible thing to describe with Terraform because the deployment pattern is at odds with Terraform's understanding of lifecycles. Using the `body` parameter here neatly skips that while still keeping things using Terraform (instead of SAM/Serverless etc).

Comment: I fully agree with you, but it's hard to change quickly the decisions made by management.

Comment: Then if you want a tool to automatically convert it to HCL unfortunately that doesn't exist and you'll have to do it by hand.

Comment: Perhaps a middle ground, that would "technically" comply with this seemingly-arbitrary rule, would be to build that `body` argument using the `jsonencode` function so that its definition can include normal Terraform expressions as needed. That's then still HCL, just _different_ HCL.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the AWS resource itself.

According to the [documentation for `aws_api_gateway_rest_api`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_rest_api.html#body) you can pass a `body` argument which is

> An OpenAPI specification that defines the set of routes and integrations to create as part of the REST API.

Then, if you need to modify the OpenAPI spec some, you could use your favorite programming language that speaks JSON (e.g. `node`, `java`, even `jq`, etc...).

For more information and to see which extensions are available, see the [API Gateway docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Actually that's the way as I currently use my OpenAPI spec in Terraform template, but I need to convert somehow my OpenAPI to HCL format, not just inject JSON.